# Users seeing other users content w/ Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm building something simple on Rails and I have Devise installed. Users log in and create *links* - I have create one account, made a few links and then when I create another account I can go to /links/5 and still see the content that another user has posted.

I'm looking to make this App as personal as possible, any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: You need something like cancan.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I came across that but was hoping there would be a easier way to implement something like this?

Comment: What do you mean, easier? It's as easy as it can get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to use a simple before_filter in the LinksController.  Something like:

```
def check_authorization
  if current_user != link.user
    redirect_to ... (Redirect as appropriate for your app)
  end
end
```

This assumes there's a link method that will get the current link.  Something like

```
def link
  @link ||= Link.find(params[:id])
end
```

As an earlier commenter mentioned, Cancan is also a viable option.